# Gantt chart for Salesforce

Tags: javascript, lightning-apps, charts, libraries

I'm looking for some library, possibly free, to make gantt chart with Salesforce classic and lightning. Do you know anything of these? Since, I will use in Lightning, it should be Locker Service compliant.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had to find/implement a Gantt chart for my company a few months ago.

The free ones that I was personally considering were:

- [Google Charts' Gantt Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart) (no idea about compatibility with Locker Service).
- [DHTMLX's Gantt Chart](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/) (has both paid and free versions, no idea about compatibility with Locker Service)

However, I ended up rolling my own Gantt Chart using the D3.js library. [This developer-relations blog post from Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) (2017-2-16) does explicitly list D3.js (v4.4.0) as being compatible with Locker Service.